# BreezeJS RequireJS support unstable (knockout example)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, breeze

As I'm trying to compile my project with breeze and requirejs for production, I'm running into multiple issues. Unrolling this, I tried starting fresh with the [Knockout RequireJS example](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-require).
After I installed MVS2013Pro I was able to run the project, but not without issues:

1. window.breeze is defined so it has been leaked to global scope (this
   should not happen with RequireJS)
2. Hitting F5 Refresh will crash with

   - Uncaught Error: Can't find breeze and/or Q (breeze savequeuing)
   - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (breeze dataservice)

With these errors I'm not even trying to establish my grunt requirejs (r optimizer) task. As these are the root of my problems.

Note: I'm not searching for a knockout solution, my stack actually is: MongoDataService+Breeze+SaveQueueing+RequireJS+AngularJS+Socket.IO+Cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *window.breeze*

You're right that `breeze` sneaks back into the browser way down at the bottom of *breeze.debug.js*:

```
if (global.window) {
    global.window.breeze = breeze;
}
```

We don't know why we put that in the code base. No one remembers. Coming at the end as it does, it clearly isn't needed by Breeze itself.

I commented it out in preliminary testing and that seems to do the trick. The *window.breeze* becomes `undefined` in the *Todo-KO-Require* sample; it remains defined (properly) in samples that do not use *require.js*.

We don't think this would be a breaking change for anyone ... and the remedy is simple enough: define it yourself at the top of your app.

We'll probably remove these lines for the next release unless we discover a reason to do otherwise.

## F5 fail?

I can't repro this at all.  I suspect your are conflating your discovery that breeze is inadvertently in the global namespace with your efforts to write an Angular app that uses *breeze.savequeuing.js*.

Why do I think this? Because the error you describe arises when trying to use *breeze.savequeuing.js* in an Angular app which is **explicitly disallowed** in the comments (line #14) of v.1.0.4:

> Depends on Breeze (which it patches) and Q.js (not for use in Angular ... yet)

You no doubt omitted *Q.js* from your required libraries and it all goes to custard from there.

I'm personally allergic to the "*save-when-user-changes-anything*" user experience that made save queuing necessary. I'm almost sorry I wrote it. But there it is.

The apparently dependence on *Q.js* is the reason it isn't available for Angular apps as written. It's actually pretty easy to make it Angular-ready now because we recently (quietly) made accessible the component that Breeze is using for promises

```
breeze.Q // returns the promises component currently used by Breeze
```

Therefore, you could change the one reference to Q on line #104 to

```
    var deferredSave = breeze.Q.defer();
```

This should work when using breeze **v.1.4.14** and later. I haven't fully tested it yet.

This change (or something like it) likely will find its way into *breeze.savequeuing.js **v.1.1.0*** (as I just pushed a non-release version of that).

Comment: About the SaveQueueing module: I first left this out but with a growing number of domain services using entityManager.saveChanges() I came over a breeze concurrent save error, so I imported the saveChanges module (wrong decision?). I could propagate model changes via socket.io too, but I feared to confuse breeze..

Comment: MongoDataService L4: if (window.breeze) { and L9:.. && !window.breeze) { avoids breeze undefined error and would be coherent with the other fileheaders

Comment: I don't think Q is the problem, savequeuing is importing it properly via requirejs. Or should it use $q?

Comment: It absolutely must use $q. I've had nothing but heartbreak mixing Q.js with $q. Use the breeze.angular service.