# BreezeJS RequireJS optimized for production

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, requirejs, breeze

Using BreezeJS, RequireJS, AngularJS with NodeJS and MongoDB as backend, I'm building a fat client application, with great success so far, as BreezeJS takes away the work to keep my domain model persisted. But it's growing and it takes now over five seconds to load all the files if they are not cached on localhost, catastrophical if you are trying to do a quick demo using a remote server..

R optimizer Warning:

> bower_components/breezejs/breeze.debug.js has more than one anonymous define.
>   May be a built file from another build system like, Ender. Skipping
>   normalization.

Trying to run the compiled production file throws:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){ return definition(global); }
>   (breeze.debug.js L10)

Has anyone gotten BreezeJS+RequireJS into production?

Comment: Related [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468484/breezejs-requirejs-support-unstable-knockout-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile my projecte leaving out breeze. With a small adjustment to the breeze mongo dataservice file header. Using r optimizer config

```
paths: {
  'breeze': 'empty:',
  'breeze-dataservice-mongo': 'empty:'
}
```

Breeze mongodataservice can be included as soon as it conforms like lib/breeze-angular.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  requirejs.config({
    paths: {
      'breeze': 'bower_components/breezejs/breeze.debug',
      'breeze-dataservice-mongo': 'lib/breeze.dataService.mongo'
    }
  });

  require(['angular', 'jquery', 'core/logger', 'fastclick', 'core/index', 'domready!'], function (angular, $, logger, fastClick) {
    logger.info('iaGastro client is booting');
    fastClick.attach(document.body);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['iaApp']);
  });
})();
```

Leaving out SaveQueueing completely, I think I can find a different solution for my concurrent save error..

@Ward:
RequireJS does static file loading, like my domain classes, also templates and json files. Now it also concatenates all my files and minifies them with one more parameter. It's probably the docs, which are not the best, because I feel I'm not the only one sometimes misunderstanding RequireJS..
Also it's error messages can be frustrating (circular dependencies..).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Todo-Require sample in the breeze.samples.js GitHub repo.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I have added a link to the related question.

Answer (score 0):

The Todo-KO-Require sample shows you how to code with require but it doesn't show you how to package things for production. You will suffer if you're asking require to download every individual file on demand.

You need to optimize with bundling and minification ... a topic outside of the breeze purview and not something we are in a hurry to produce. Perhaps you'd like to take that bull by the horns and share with the rest of us.

### Why worry?

[update, 2 July 2014]

Let's take a step back and rediscover the point of all this.  **What is require doing for you?**

I've used it with KO as a vehicle for dependency injection. That's its role in Durandal.

Angular comes with its own DI which reduces the role of require in an Ng app to asynchronous file loader. That's usually "meh" for me, in part because one soon encounters the file-loading-flurry that you describe. That leads to bundling which is a headache and can as easily be done with other tooling.

> I see the value in a large applications with dynamically loaded modules. But Ng is woeful in this regard quite apart from the async file loading. Something they'll address in v.2.

I'm happy to leave you to a contrary opinion. So let's consider what would happen if we can't fix this problem. **What if breeze cannot be optimized with *r*?**

My instinct is that **it isn't really optimal to bundle breeze with anything else anyway!**

The minimized breeze is rather large in itself. It is not evident to me that you would gain any performance advantage at all by bundling it with your application assets. Sure you want to keep the number of server requests down. But are two requests with 1/2 the payload slower than one big request? Do you know for your target environment?

I'm not the kind of pedant who insists that every script be delivered by require. It's trivial to load BreezeJS separately with a script tag and then make it available to other require-aware modules (I shall assume you know how to do this). What would be horrible about that?

While we look forward to your repro sample (see my comment below), I may have difficulty justifying priority attention to this issue. Convince me otherwise.

Comment: There is still the problem in the breeze main file header, related [FeatureRequest](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5137605-also-support-almond-for-amd)

Comment: Are you getting that first error *before* optimizing or during the *r optimizer*?  It would help if you could produce (as a gist?) a tiny repro so we could investigate. Better yet, figure out what's wrong and make a suggestion. This is open source which delights in community assistance.